# Case statement wont return sum for rolling 12 month calendar

Tags: sql, netsuite

```
CASE 
    WHEN {trandate} BETWEEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS({today}, -12)) AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS({today}, -13)) 
        THEN {quantity} 
        ELSE 0 
END
```

I want this code to return the sum of the items sold for a specific month, but it just returns 0 if my date range is the previous 12 rolling months ...

Comment: Flip the order of your dates. You're basically saying `between '2021-06-30' and '2021-05-31'`.

Comment: @Andrew It still will not return a value. Maybe I'm not using the right operators?

Comment: If you want to do a sum, you need a sum!

SUM(CASE WHEN {trandate} BETWEEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS({today},-12)) AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS({today},-13)) THEN {quantity} ELSE 0 END)

Comment: I would not use `last_day` or `between`. Instead truncate {today} to the month (in Oracle `trunc(sySdate,'MM')` and construct the case expression as `SUM(CASE WHEN {trandate} >= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), -13) AND {trandate} < ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), -12) THEN {quantity} ELSE 0 END)`  not sure if thsi translates to netsuite but using `between` can be a big problem if the `transdate` precision is finer than just date

Comment: Show some sample data that you think should meet your criteria. Show all the relevant parts of your query as well.